# Derived table not recognised in where command

Tags: sql-server, subquery, derived-table

I am new and still learning so please excuse my codes. I have googled and as last resort posting for help. Hope one of the senior programmers can help.

What I am trying to achieve: which course has below average number of students?

I am using SQL Server Management Studio v18.

My code does not work and I can not understand why derived table is not being accepted. I am aware that I can create another subquery and achieve it but still want to understand why derived table C in this case is not working?

Please help with explanation and suggest simplest way to achieve this query.

```
select 
    c.course, c.num_of_students
from
    (select 
         course, count(pname) as num_of_students
     from 
         Studies
     group by 
         COURSE) c
where 
    c.num_of_students < (select avg(c.num_of_students) from c);
```

I get this error:

> Invalid object name 'c'

This invalid object name is highlighted in the WHERE clause line.

Data displays properly in the preview.

Data:

| PNAME | INSTITUTE | COURSE | COURSEFEE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ANAND | SABHARI | PGDCA | 4500 |
| ALTAF | COIT | DCA | 7200 |
| JULIANA | BDPS | MCA | 22000 |
| KAMALA | PRAGATHI | DCA | 5000 |
| MARY | SABHARI | PGDCA | 4500 |
| NELSON | PRAGATHI | DAP | 6200 |
| PATRICK | PRAGATHI | DCAP | 5200 |
| QADIR | APPLE | HDCA | 14000 |
| RAMESH | SABHARI | PGDCA | 4500 |
| REBECCA | BRILLIANT | DCAP | 11000 |
| REMITHA | BDPS | DCS | 6000 |
| REVATHI | SABHARI | DAP | 5000 |
| VIJAYA | BDPS | DCA | 48000 |

Comment: If you need to reference a derived table twice use a CTE instead. The derived table definition needs to be repeated after every `from` that uses that definition (and you would need to give it a new alias on the second occasion too)

Comment: If this query is going to be a one and done thing then squillman's answer is the most effective way of doing it; but if the average is going to be used further down in the script, then it's worth looking at variables and temporary tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derived tables have limited scope within a query and can only be referenced once after `FROM`.  You have a few options, the best of which is a CTE:

```
WITH c AS (
    SELECT
        course, COUNT(pname) as num_of_students
    FROM Studies
    GROUP BY course
)
SELECT
    c.course, c.num_of_students
FROM c
WHERE
    c.num_of_students < (SELECT AVG(c.num_of_students) FROM c);
```

Additional options, although probably less desirable in this situation unless you need to use the results in your derived table in other queries, would be to define a temp table or a table variable:

Temp table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #c;
SELECT
    course, COUNT(pname) as num_of_students
INTO #c
FROM Studies
GROUP BY course;

SELECT
    c.course, c.num_of_students
FROM #c c
WHERE
    c.num_of_students < (SELECT AVG(c.num_of_students) FROM c);

DROP TABLE #c;
```

Table variable:

```
DECLARE @c TABLE (
    course VARCHAR(100),
    num_of_students INT
);

INSERT @c (course, num_of_students)
SELECT course, COUNT(pname)
FROM Studies
GROUP BY course;

SELECT
    c.course, c.num_of_students
FROM @c c
WHERE
    c.num_of_students < (SELECT AVG(c.num_of_students) FROM c);
```